# Как данный пример написать более, оптимизирование и лучше

Tags: c#, discord, таймер

В чем суть, я хочу сделать команду которая, будет заглушать пользователя на определенное время как это работает бот выдает роль которая запрещает пользователю писать в чат, и через определенное время снимается автоматически, в моем случае 10 сек. Как бы команда работает, но мне хотелось бы написать данное решение более оптимизированным и так скажем на другом более высоком уровне, я пробовал через таймер (System.Timers) и у меня не получилось снять роль с пользователя которому я выдал мут (вариант ниже который не получился)

```
   //Рабочий пример
   [Command("Mute")]
    public async Task Mute(SocketGuildUser user)
    {    
        var roleId = Context.Guild.GetRole(771292105783771136);
       
         //Выдача роли мута
        await user.AddRoleAsync(roleId) ;

         Thread.Sleep(10000);
          
        //Снятие роли мута
        await user.RemoveRoleAsync(roleId);
    }

       //Не рабочий пример
        [Command("Mute")]
        public async Task Mute(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var _timer = new Timer();
            var roleId = Context.Guild.GetRole(771292105783771136);
           
            await user.AddRoleAsync(roleId);

            _timer = new Timer(10000);

            await user.AddRoleAsync(roleId);

            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Enabled = true;

            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;

                
        }

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

          //По моему пониманию как работает таймер в этом методе я должен снять с пользователя роль и остановить таймер
          _timer.Stop(); 
        }
```

Comment: что если в рабочем примере заменить `Thread.Sleep(10000);` на `await Task.Delay(10000);` ?

Comment: `Как бы команда работает, но мне хотелось бы написать данное решение более оптимизированным и так скажем на другом более высоком уровне` это требует пояснений, так как у каждого свое предсталение об оптимизации и высоких уровнях.

Comment: Таймер  и задержки в командах это плохо, ибо что будет с человеком, если вдруг ваш бот выключится и пропустит "тик" разбана? Правильно, он останется в вечном бане.

Comment: @tym32167 Ну мне бы хотелось написать через таймер, т.к я думаю, что таймер полезный, и более оптимизированный чем Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда каким способ лучше решить данную проблему?

Comment: и да сразу добавлю через базу данных не хочу решать данную проблему

Comment: Таймер это таймер, Thread.Sleep это Thread.Sleep. Они между собой слабо связаны.

Comment: Если не хотите через базу, то ваши все баны бесполезны, ибо малейший сбой, рестарт или ещё что и ваш сервер в хаосе) Тут как не крути, нужно сделать запись что id... Забанен на xx по причине yy. А уже дальше вы можете без проблем найти все "протухшие" записи и сделать с ними обратное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Все понял вас, просто почему не хотел через бд потому-что сама база будет увеличиваться в размере, но я решил так сделать как у человека мут спадает, очищать его поле данных

Comment: Не удаляйте сразу запись, мой вам совет. Иногда история нарушений очень сильно бывает полезна. Дайте ей срок годности, например пол года, после которого будете удалять. Ну а так да, вам нужно хранить данные, где либо, без этого такое сделать стабильно вряд-ли получится.

Comment: Либо вы готовы мириться с тем, что возможны ситуации, когда процесс умрёт и часть забаненных останется навечно забаненными, либо вы обязаны подумать о персистентности данных в надёжное хранилище, устойчивое к сбоям. Вы только базы так не любите или вам остальные методы персистентности не нравятся тоже? Скажем, файл на диске. Тут просто "либо - либо" и вы когда накушаетесь разгребать руками все баны зафейленные -- просто полюбите базы за их устойчивость к сбоям.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я вчера забыл спросить важную вещь, которую я не знаю в чем суть. Допустим в бд записалось время мута, но к примеру чтобы проверить закончилось время мута у пользователя или нет, нужно написать команду, которая проверит если время мута закончилось то снимется роль если нет то бот выдаст сколько времени осталось. А как мне этот процесс автоматизировать, чтобы бот сам автоматически снимал роль когда у пользователя время закончилось

Comment: @whitetears Если по уму, то такое обычно делают на уровне баз, например Redis, которая позволяет хранить `ключ-значение` и подписываться на [уведомления](https://redis.io/topics/notifications), по которым уже и делают нужные действия. Если по-простому, то я бы сделал некий глобальный `Task` в котором будет бесконечно крутиться цикл с задержкой раз в .. сек, ну и событие, которое оно будет вызывать (аля `while(true){ Tick?.Invoke(); await Task.Delay(...); }`, то есть некий асинхронный таймер, на который дальше уже подписываемся где надо и вызываем нужные апдейты.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ честно говоря, где-то на 30% понял вашу мысль, но а что если написать к примеру отдельный бесконечный цикл, который будет проверять всех пользователей, на окончание время их мута

Comment: @whitetears А что не ясно в моем сообщение? Вроде элементарные вещи говорю... В любом случае, вам надо фоном, раз в N сек/мин делать обращение к тем записям с банами и с "протухшими" делать нужные действия. Как вы это будете делать - дело ваше, я же выше предложил один глобальный цикл, дабы не плодить их под каждую команду, как вон в Unity (если пробовали), там есть у кадого скрипта Update метод, который вызывается каждый кадр, вот вам нечто такое надо сделать.